# how to remove .py from the url in jython

Tags: java, python, url-rewriting, jython

I am trying to remove .py extension from the url, I am using this tutorial: http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/SimpleWebApps.html

my web.xml is as follows:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.python.util.PyServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.py</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>NewJythonServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>NewJythonServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>NewJythonServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/NewJythonServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>NewJavaServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>NewJavaServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>NewJavaServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/NewJavaServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    </web-app>
```

I have also tried putting /* in url mapping..but its giving error!
Can someone guide me for this.

thanks

## EDIT - 1

Here is what i get when i put `/*` in url mapping:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /jythonapp/NewJythonServlet

type Status report

message /jythonapp/NewJythonServlet

description The requested resource (/jythonapp/NewJythonServlet) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.30
```

Comment: What's the error message? Where are you putting the .*? Is this running in Tomcat?

Comment: I have edited my question with the stacktrace.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377541/servlet-mapping-url-pattern

Comment: @ethrbunny could you please tell me as to what exactly i should do rather then the link to some question? because the link is for servlet mapping..and i have tried `/*`

Comment: My next guess would be that the .py file is not in the correct location.

Comment: @ethrbunny I have create a web app structure.. and kept the .py file just in the directory, that is: jythonapps/NewJythonServlet.py, jythonapps/WEB-INF

Answer (score 0):

Im wondering if the 'jythonapp' folder needs to be specified in the 'servlet-mapping' section.

EG:

```
<url-pattern>/jythonapp/NewJythonServlet</url-pattern>
```

(I don't think that's quite right but its been a while since I've used Tomcat. )

Im also thinking that the 'jythonapp' folder should be a sub of 'webapps'. --> http://www.sethanil.com/ot/10

What URL are you using for this test?

Comment: Is 'jythonapp' in the 'webapps' folder?

Comment: $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/jythonapp/NewJythonServlet.py

Comment: I don't think the .py goes on the end

Comment: it goes! otherwise its not running!

Comment: Right but jython is run-time compiling your python into a servlet. Turn on tomcat debug logging and see if there is any more info.