# remove .py from the jython based web application url

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jython, web.xml, jython-2.5

This is the follow up of this question [how to remove .py from the url in jython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636156/how-to-remove-py-from-the-url-in-jython) , I couldnt get it solved till now, and hope to get some  more suggestions for it. 
Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.python.util.PyServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>NewJythonServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>NewJythonServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NewJythonServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/NewJythonServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/serv/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I think the url had to start with something that isn't a wildcard