# Url mapping of servlets

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

Consider following code snippet of web.xml:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In above code snippet what does

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

represents?

is /and /* in above url-pattern same thing?

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377541/servlet-mapping-url-pattern

Answer (score 2):

> is /and /* in above url-pattern same thing?

**No.**

[JSR-000315 Java Servlet 3.0 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/)

### SRV.11.2 Specification of Mappings

In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is used to define
mappings:

> - A string beginning with a `/` character and ending with a `/*` suffix is used
>     for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a `*.` prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - A string containing only the `/` character indicates the *"default" servlet* of
>     the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context
>     path and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

Answer (score 1):

**Double asterisk**

/** will match any number of (0 or more) levels in a path, eg. it would match both /file and  /some/path/file.

**Single Asterisk**

A single asterisk /* only matches 0 or more characters (not path levels) so it would match /file but  not /some/path/file.

**No Asterisk**

A single slash / would only match the root path.