# What is the difference between these url mapping patterns?

Tags: java, web.xml, url-pattern

What is the difference between these url mappings ?

```
<url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
```

and

```
<url-pattern>/servlet/*</url-pattern>
```

and

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

and

```
 <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Related to this, perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377541/servlet-mapping-url-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that root (`/`) means the context root of your web application.

```
<url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
```

Matches to a specific resource that maps directly to path `servlet` under root(/)

```
<url-pattern>/servlet/*</url-pattern>
```

Matches to any resource under `/servlet`.

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

Matches to any resource under root(`/`).

```
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
```

Matches to a specific file pattern i.e. that ends with `.do`.

Answer (score 2):

URL patterns are explained in the [Servlet 3.0 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/), section *12.2 Specification of Mapping*:

> In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is used to define mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a `/` character and ending with a `/*` suffix is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a `*.` prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the application's context root, i.e., requests of the form `http://host:port/<context-root>/`. In this case the path info is `/` and the servlet path and context path is empty string (““).
> - A string containing only the `/` character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.