# Require Tomcat configuration to restrict exe's from downloading

Tags: tomcat, servlets, browser, download

I have a web application hosted in Apache Tomcat
I  am looking for apache configuration to restrict downloading exe's when I hit the URL

when I hit `http://<server_name>/abc/xyz.exe`   application works normally                                                                                                         if appended with append '/' to the end.. like `http://<server_name>/abc/xyz.exe\`     the junk executable xyz.exe  is downloaded on to the browser

Here is my web.xml content

```
  <init-param>
    <param-name>_webengine0</param-name>
    <param-value>web:local</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>web:local</param-name>
    <param-value>pdmweb.exe</param-value>
  </init-param>
```

can you please let me know if there is any apache configuration to be placed to restrict file downloads (specifically .exe) from application

Comment: Does that mean you're installing a Java Webserver (tomcat) to execute Windows Binaries? I've never heard of such a setup. You might want to provide a [mcve], see [ask]

Comment: looks like a duplicate of [Servlet mapping: url-pattern for URLs with trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377541/servlet-mapping-url-pattern-for-urls-with-trailing-slash) , please close your post if so.

Comment: No Olaf,  My requirement is not to download windows  binaries ...  i am looking for apache configuration to restrict downloading exe's when i hit the url ...  when i hit `http://<server_name>/abc/xyz.exe`      application works normally                                                                                                         problem is when i append '/' to the end.. like `http://<server_name>/abc/xyz.exe/`

Comment: That's a tiny snippet of web.xml (not really fitting the [mcve] approach: it's minimal, but not reproducible)- while I'm not asking for all of the file, to me it's unclear what you're configuring with these `init-param`s. And again, using Tomcat to execute Windows Binaries sounds quite counterintuitive (I can't imagine what else you're doing with them if you're not offering them for  download)

Comment: Olaf, my intent is not to download the exe file ....my exe contains an jsp page which is the starting login page of my application. I wanted the jsp to display the login... But Ironically when i just mistakenly adds an '/' to the end the url .... the exe is getting downloaded thru browser